# wordpress database connection error after while / fixed after reboot

Tags: database, wordpress

I have a problem that my wordpress site gives a database connection after a while of using the site. After I use sudo reboot the site comes back online again. The settings of my database connection are correct.

What can cause this and why is it fixed after reboot?

My error.log: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=51432250094714017709

Can you guys see something strange in here? the website dietsmartertoday.com doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

There could be several things that would cause this to happen. Have you checked your server logs to see what is going on?

Your MYSQL database could be crashing or you might have a memory leak / are running out of memory.

I would first check your server logs, but if you are getting a "Memory Exhausted error" add the following line to your wp-config.php file.

define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Where can I find the server log on my Ubuntu server?

Comment: If you are using Apache it would be located in /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: this is my log.. i added the define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M'); and it seemed to work, but still crashing random.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, your mysqld service is crashing. You can check/confirm this via the server error logs (as @tux has described).

One of the common causes of this would be shortage of memory. To fix this, as described by @tux again, try

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');
```

If that doesn't fix it, your next option would be to check if a swap partition is available and enabled on your server. In absence of swap, if the operating system runs out of ram, it would lead to a crash (with unpredictable outcome).

You can check for swap with the following command:

```
# sudo swapon -s
```

You can also run

```
# sudo top
```

to get more detailed information about memory and swap.

If there is no swap, you can - and should - create it. The exact commands to do this would depend on the linux distro you'er running, so you can google

{your linux distro} how to create a swap partition

Once the swap partition is active, the problem should go away.

Comment: [my error.log][can you guys see something strang in here? the website dietsmartertoday.com doesn't exist anymore.

http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=51432250094714017709